# Limpar o Cache do navegador após subir versão

Tags: php, javascript, navegador-de-internet, cache

Tenho o seguinte cenário: 
A cada mês lançamos novas versões para nossos clientes, e muito das vezes o nossos clientes ligam informando que funcionalidade X não esta funcionando da forma que deveria funcionar. Porque normalmente está executando uma função que é da versão anterior exatamente por causa do cache do navegador, nesse caso o cliente tem que clicar CTRL+F5 ou até mesmo limpar todo o seu cache para a funcionalidade X funcionar corretamente.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma classe em php ou em outra linguagem também que possa ser implementada em php para realizar a limpeza desse cache. 
porque pra tal situação posso usar o banco de dados para verificar se estamos subindo versão para o cliente ou não e executar a limpeza desse navegador.

Bom hoje nós armazenamos em cache todos os JS para ganhar um pouco a mais em desempenho, usamos o seguinte:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 31536000");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=900, pre-check=3600");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000");
```

Procurei bastante pela internet, e todos que eu procurei não obtive sucesso no que eu estava de fato querendo executar, por ultimo tentei a função propria do php

> Clearstatcache()

Comment: Acredito que adicionando no header o `Last-Modified` o problema seja resolvido. Isso irá informar o browser qual a data em que o arquivo foi alterado, que no seu caso seria a data em que a nova versão ficou disponível. Assim o navegador não iria utilizar a versão em cache e sim a versão do servidor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta que o nome do ou dos ficheiros de JS e CSS tenham um nome variável..
Por exemplo:

- O que deve ter agora: omeucss.css || omeujs.js
- O que deve passar a ter: omeucssv12 || omeujs45.js

Isto pode ser feito automaticamente, depende do seu sistema.. eu aqui junto todo o js num so ficheiro (tal como o css) e no html chamo o url: meusite.pt/js/ quando ele chama o ficheiro /js/omeujs.js
Nesse momento ele ve se o ficheiro ja foi gerado, caso não tenha sido ele gera (tendo em conta a variável) e apresenta o resultado js :)

**EDITE**

Esqueci-me da parte do htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^js/(.+).js$ /js/ [NC,L]
```

Abraço e boa sorte!

Comment: uso a tecnica muito semelhante, só que em vez de mudar o nome do arquivo eu só passo outro valor como parametro tipo `$LAB.script('../js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js?nocache='+Math.random())`

Comment: Sim, seria a forma mais fácil ate, bom comentário ;) A forma que falei para coisas pequenas é capaz de dar mais trabalho.. eu uso assim porque tenho outras coisas a correr no controller js...

Comment: As duas técnicas funcionaram pra mim agradeço

Comment: @PauloHenrique A solução é válida, mas você não quer manter em cache os scripts? Imagina que uma versão é lançada hoje e outra será lançada daqui 2 meses. Todas vez que alguém fizer um pedido ao servidor, o ficheiro JS será enviado uma vez que a resposta ao request não será um 304, ou seja, cai por terra qualquer sistema de cache.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Sim, porém são duas situações os arquivos globais de JS como por exemplo os jquery-1.9.2.js  e os arquivos custom.js  que no meu caso os custons entravam no cache o que gerava problema pra me mas criei uma função onde ele adiciona um parametro no final dos arquivos JS que são diferentes das entradas globais, ae funcionou da forma que gostaria, ou seja todos os arquivos globais entram em cache mas os custom que estão em constante mudança não entram, perco um pouco quando os custons não forem alterados ae sim é um erro mas estudarei essa falha com mais calma :D muito obr mestre

Answer (score 4):

## Solução

- Renomeie as extensões de todos os arquivos JS (que acredito que sejam os arquivos que estejam dando problema com cache) para .php
- Defina o tipo de conteúdo da página JS usando `header("Content-type: text/javascript");`
- Crie um script PHP responsável por validar se é necessário ou não limpar o cache.

Pra validar se é necessário, ou não, fazer a limpeza do cache, você pode uar cookies.

```
<?php

$versaoAtual = 1;

if (!isset($_COOKIE['versao'])) {
    setcookie('versao', $versaoAtual, (time() + (60 * 24 * 3600)));
} else {
    $versao = (int) $_COOKIE['versao'];

    if ($versao < $versaoAtual) {
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: Mon, 20 Jul 2000 03:00:00 GMT");
        header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, cachehack=" . time());
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate");
        header("Cache-Control: post-check=-1, pre-check=-1", false);

        setcookie('versao', $versaoAtual, (time() + (60 * 24 * 3600)));
    }
}
```

Pronto, com isso acredito qe resolva seu problema. Lembre-se de sempre atualizar o valor da variável `versaoAtual`, pois é com base nela que o PHP vai decidir se o cliente precisa limpar o cache.

## Extra

Acredito (não tenho certeza), que você também poderia usar o CloudFlare para isso. No painel deles tem uma opção `purge cache`, onde você define quais arquivos você quer remover do cache.

Isso iria remover o cache do servidor da CloudFlare, só não sei se removeria também do cliente, ainda não tive tempo pra analisar como esse purge cache funciona.

É isso, espero ter contribuído de alguma maneira.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes, a função header envia instruções para o navegador do cliente.

Comment: Sim sim, me desculpe, apaguei o comentário, porém o sistema acima ele já implementou, pelo menos o que eu percebi. O problema seria resolvido se ele adicionasse no header o `Last-Modified`, informando o browser qual a última modificação no arquivo.

Answer (score 3):

Nenhuma combinação de cabeçalho é 100% garantida.

O mais garantido é adicionar um parâmetro como query de url.

Exemplo: `/js/arquivo.js?20160227`.

Assim garante que quando modificar, será baixado sempre a versão nova. Basta modificar o número. Nesse caso usamos data.

Suponha que amanhã modifique novamente, então modificaria para `/js/arquivo.js?20160228`.

O cache dos navegadores existe para reduzir o tráfego de dados, economizando largura de banda. Nesse esquema, usando um parâmetro novo a cada nova versão, garantirá que o cache mantenha a versão corrente e sempre estará seguro de que uma nova versão será sempre atualizada, independente do cache do browser.

Ao invés de usar data atual, também pode usar a versão do arquivo.

Exemplo: `/js/arquivo.js?1.0.0.2`.

Também pode usar qualquer coisa aleatória, desde que não repita um anterior já usado.

Exemplo: `/js/arquivo.js?qualquer_coisa_serve`.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que adicionando no header o `Last-Modified`  o problema seja resolvido.

Isso irá informar o navegador qual a data em que o arquivo foi alterado, que no seu caso seria a data em que a nova versão ficou disponível.

Assim sendo, o navegador não iria utilizar a versão em cache e sim a versão do servidor. A versão em cache seria substituída pela versão do servidor.
Alterando o código informado na pergunta:

```
//mktime(hora, minuto, segundos, mes, dia, ano)
//Abaixo indicamos que houve uma alteração no ficheiro a meia noite do dia 26/02/2016 
$newVersion = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 26, 2016));

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 31536000");
header("Last-Modified: " . $newVersion . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=900, pre-check=3600");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000");
```