# Trocar Imagem e limpar cache

Tags: javascript

Eu estou exibindo em minha pagina uma imagem chamada **pontuacao.png**, e eu gostaria de que o javascript limpe o cache e exiba a imagem e repita isso a cada 100 milissegundos.

Isso é possível? Alguém me ajudaria com um exemplo em javascript e html?

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tenta dar uma lida aqui, vê se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file

Comment: A resposta pra sua pergunta é: não é possível limpar o cache do navegador usando JavaScript, os navegadores não permitem isso. Existem outras formas de conseguir o que você quer, muitas alias. Por exemplo, você poderia jogar um nome diferente pra imagem a cada atualização, assim não teria cache, ou poderia usar os parâmetros GET assim: pontuacao.png?v=1 e ir sempre alterando o valor de 1. Não sei como é o seu projeto, mas acredito também que não seja necessário uma imagem, talvez dê pra fazer com texto, o que seria melhor.

Comment: Vou explicar melhor ( Eu tenho uma camera fotografica que bate foto a cada 100 milisegundos e envia para meu computador, eu gostaria de pegar essas fotos em tempo real e exibir no site, ficaria como se fosse uma animação ). Mas a maquina sempre substitui a imagem anterior, então eu gostaria que o site fizesse uma atualização sem refresh e exiba a imagem atual, será que tem como fazer ? qual o jeito correto de se fazer isso ?

Comment: Entendi. Dá pra fazer e não é difícil, mas tenho uma dúvida. O site tem que atualizar a imagem a cada 100 milissegundos também? Se isso for em uma ambiente intranet, talvez até dê, mas se for na web, acho que não vai dar tempo de carregar a imagem.

Comment: Então, estou fazendo localmente.

Comment: Não parece uma boa lógica, repetir um processo como esse a cada 100 milisegundos. Se puder explicar o contexto disso, o motivo, etc, pode ter solução mais adequada. Mas se quiser continuar assim, isso aqui pode ajudar a dar uma ideia de como exibir sempre a imagem nova: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115436/4793

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de PHP e nem de requisições AJAX. Eu fiz isso num projeto de uma maneira bem simples. Apenas colocando querystring na própria imagem. Não precisa criar arquivo php. Apenas coloque no src da imagem um timestamp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function autoloadImg() {
                var src = $("#img").attr('src');

                if( src.indexOf('?') > 0 ) 
                    src = src.substring( 0, src.indexOf('?') );

                var d = new Date();
                $("#img").attr("src", src + '?time=' + d.getTime() );
            };

            $(document).ready( function(){
                setInterval("autoloadImg()", 100);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="imagem.png" id="img">
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Com base nos comentários do autor da pergunta, aqui está uma das possibilidades de atingir o objetivo desejado de forma simples e eficaz.

Crie um arquivo PHP chamado `get-image.php` e coloque o seguinte código dentro dele

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
        $numRand = rand();
        echo "<img src='imagem.png?{$numRand}'>";
    }
```

Agora, crie um arquivo PHP ou HTML, com o nome que preferir e coloque o seguinte código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Burlando cache do navegador com AJAX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="imagem"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function attImagem() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get-image.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: 'ajax=null',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#imagem").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
      
        setInterval("attImagem()", 1000);
    </script>
</html>
```

Explicando a lógica

Quando você entrar no seu arquivo principal (o que contem o código HTML e JavaScript), será incluído o jQuery e, uma função que será disparada a cada segundo. Essa função irá chamar via AJAX (sem atualizar a página) o arquivo get-image.php

O arquivo get-image.php tem a função de gerar um número aleatório e atribuir ao nome da imagem como um parâmetro GET, fazendo o navegador entender que aquela imagem é outra, e não a mesma que foi carregada anteriormente.

Considerações finais

- Se desejar alterar o nome da imagem que será solicitada, procure a `linha 5` do arquivo `get-image.php`, e altere o imagem.png para o nome da sua imagem, bem como o caminho (caso esteja em outro diretório).
- No script acima, a imagem será exibida na div chamada `imagem`, se quiser, pode alterar o nome, mas faça isso tanto no ID da div, quanto dentro da função AJAX, onde tem `$("#imagem").html(data);`
- Para aumentar ou diminuir o intervalo entre as atualizações, altere o valor `1000 (em milissegundos)`.
- Se tratando de uma imagem, colocar um valor muito baixo pode fazer com que a imagem não seja exibida e também poderá sobrecarregar o servidor onde a imagem esteja hospedada.

Comment: Eu acabei de fazer o teste e não apareceu nenhuma imagem dentro da div.

Comment: Colocou o código exatamente como está aí? A imagem tem o nome imagem.png? Está no mesmo local do get-image.php? Tem o PHP instalado no seu PC? Se a resposta pra tudo isso for sim, ela tem que aparecer.

Comment: Eu enviei os arquivos para meu servidor online com php e fiz tudo certinho, coloquei a imagem na mesma pasta do php. Estranho não estar aparecendo. será que o problema esta no ajax ?

Comment: Estava faltando um > pra fechar a tag <img> no get-image.php, já corrigi. Copia de novo e tenta.

Comment: Agora deu certo, mas acho que não irá dar certo com 100 milisegundos.

Comment: Hm, mas porque?

Comment: Esta funcionando, mas a pessoa não pode perceber a transição de uma foto para outra, então teria que ser uns 100miliegundos e assim a imagem não carrega, pois é uma foto de 400 x 400 pixels, eu acho que só conseguirei fazer isso usando flash mesmo. A sua idéia é otima, mas tem esse problema.

Comment: Eu testei usando uma imagem hd de 400kb e não deu pra perceber a transição. Talvez pelo fato e a imagem vir direto da câmera, ela vem com uma qualidade muito alta e consequentemente o tamanho deve ficar entre 1.5mb ~ 4mb. Nesse caso não tem o que fazer a não ser usar uma API pra diminuir o tamanho dessas imagens e depois exibi-las. Ou procurar outro método.

Comment: Não, eu criei uma imagem no photoshop de 400 x 400 pixels e joguei no servidor, depois eu criei uma outra diferente com o mesmo nome e joguei no servidor e fiquei olhando e deu para perceber a transição, eu posso fazer um video e te mandar, você quer ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36870/discussion-between-desenvolvedor-and-clayderson-ferreira).